# jQuery AJAX not working on Firefox

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, firefox

I have a function and an AJAX call. After clicking it gets the function and function works fine, on alert it shows the data, but after that it does not send the data to PHP. Any ideas why this happens on Firefox? It works well in IE and Chrome.

```
function siparisolustur() {
    var toplamsiparis = $('.urunrow').length;
    var i = null;
    var siparisid = $("#siparis_id").text();

    var name = $("#siparisad").val();
    var surname = $("#siparissoyad").val();
    var tel = $("#siparistel").val();
    var adres = $("#sepetadres").val();
    var semt = $("#sepetilce").val();
    var sehir = $("#sepetsehir").val();
    var notlar = $("#siparisnotu").val();
    var odeme = $('input[name="odemeyontemi"]:checked').attr("id");

    bilgiDataString = '&siparisid=' + siparisid + '&name=' + name + '&surname=' + surname + '&tel=' + tel + '&adres=' + adres + '&semt=' + semt + '&sehir=' + sehir + '&notlar=' + notlar + '&odeme=' + odeme;

    alert(bilgiDataString);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://www.xxxxx.com/procc/xxxxxxxxxx.php",
        data: bilgiDataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {

        }
    });

    $("#payForm").submit(function (e) {
        var siparisdurdur = 0;
        var ad = $("#siparisad").val();
        var soyad = $("#siparissoyad").val();
        var tel = $("#siparistel").val();
        var adres = $("#sepetadres").val();
        var ilce = $("#sepetilce").val();
        var sehir = $("#sepetsehir").val();
        var sepeturunadetget = parseInt($("#sepeturunsayisi").text());

        if (ad == "" || soyad == "" || tel == "" || adres == "" || ilce == "" || sehir == "" || sepeturunadetget < 1) {
            siparisdurdur = 1;
        }

        if (ad == "") {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#siparisad").css("border-    color", "#cd2828")
        } else {
            $("#siparisad").css("border-color", "#d1d2e6");
        }
        if (soyad == "") {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#siparissoyad").css("border-color", "#cd2828")
        } else {
            $("#siparissoyad").css("border-color", "#d1d2e6");
        }
        if (tel == "") {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#siparistel").css("border-color", "#cd2828")
        } else {
            $("#siparistel").css("border-color", "#d1d2e6");
        }
        if (adres == "") {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#sepetadres").css("border-color", "#cd2828")
        } else {
            $("#sepetadres").css("border-color", "#d1d2e6");
        }
        if (ilce == "") {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#sepetilce").css("border-color", "#cd2828")
        } else {
            $("#sepetilce").css("border-color", "#d1d2e6")
        }
        if (sehir == "") {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#sepetsehir").css("border-color", "#cd2828")
        } else {
            $("#sepetsehir").css("border-color", "#d1d2e6")
        }
        if (blocksubmit == 1) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#personalinfosubmit").fadeOut("fast").fadeIn("fast").fadeOut("fast").fadeIn("fast");
        }
        if (sepeturunadetget < 1) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#shoppingcost").css("color", "#cd2828");
            $("#shoppingcost").fadeOut("fast").fadeIn("fast").fadeOut("fast").fadeIn("fast");
        }

        if (blocksubmit == 0 && siparisdurdur == 0) {
            siparisolustur();
        }
    });
```

Comment: check the network tab and console for the errors/informations.

Comment: I can't remember exactly, but I had a similar problem. It had to do with  preventDefault();-behaviour! Maybe you can check that ...

Comment: I solved the problem.. Submit goes to other page before ajax is done proessing the data.. I delayed the redirect for like half second and it worked.. Its about speed of FF.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.. Submit goes to other page before ajax is done proessing the data.. I delayed the redirect for like half second and it worked.. Its about speed of FF

Answer (score 0):

I see that you've posted a solution already:

> *Submit goes to other page before ajax is done proessing the data.. I delayed the redirect for like half second and it worked.*

Seriously, you should not be relying on a solution like this.

Timing issues like this are known as a "race condition", ie where two events are effectively in a race to see which one will finish first; you're expecting one to always win, and you get a bug if they finish in the wrong order.

It's a very well defined category of bug (even if Ajax is fairly new, situations like this have existed since the begining of computer science), and the solution is *not* to slow down one of the events in the hope that you'll force it to always lose. That is always the wrong solution.

The correct solution is usually to trigger the second event only after the first one has finished. In your case, this would mean firing the `submit` event from inside the ajax `success` method.